# Why after some times the timer in the backgroundworker dowork event stop?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the event code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {
                completed = true;
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
                    {


                        if (checkBox1.Checked)
                        {
                            mute = true;
                            soundPlay = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mute = false;
                            soundPlay = true;
                            NudgeMe();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                        stop_alarm = true;

                    }

                    tempCpuValue = core.cpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, cpu, this, data, tempCpuValue, button1, numericUpDown1.Value);
                    tempGpuValue = core.gpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, data, tempGpuValue, button1, numericUpDown1.Value);
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => data = new List<string>()));
                    tempCpuValue = core.cpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, cpu, this, data, tempCpuValue, button1, numericUpDown1.Value);
                    tempGpuValue = core.gpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, data, tempGpuValue, button1, numericUpDown1.Value);
                    if (CelsiusFahrenheit == true)
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => label5.Text = Core.d.ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => label5.Text = Core.GpulabelTemp.ToString()));
                    }
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => label11.Text = Core.CpulabelTemp.ToString()));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = (int)Core.GpulabelTemp));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => label16.Text = Core.speed));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => Core.getallmemoryusage(processName)));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => label17.Text = Core.privateMemeory));
                    if (Core.videoCardType("ati", "nvidia") == true)
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = Core.graphicCardNvidia));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = Core.graphicCardAti));
                    }
                    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    PopulateApplications();
                    sw.Stop();
                    int msec = 1000 - (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    if (msec < 1) msec = 1;   // Don't consume 100% CPU
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(msec);
                }
            }
        }
```

If i use a breakpoint on the line:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

I see it stop there every second or so.
And after few times could be 2-3 minutes it stop. The breakpoint never stop again on this line.
Sometimes after a minute sometimes after 3-4 minutes it just stop.

The question is if there is something wrong with the DoWork event code ?
Or maybe the problem is in the PopulateApplications() method ?

My goal is to use timer inside the background worker and call the method PopulateApplications() every second.
This method PopulateApplications() get the memory usage for each running process and display it in a dataGridView:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
                DoubleBufferedd(dataGridView1, true);
                int rcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                int rcurIndex = 0;
                foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                        try
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(p.MainModule.FileName))
                            {
                                        memoryUsage = Core.getallmemoryusage(p.ProcessName);                                    
                                        var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                                        Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                                        ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                                        ima = (Image)(new Bitmap(ima, new Size(25, 25)));
                                        String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                                        if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
                                        {
                                            var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex];
                                            currentRow.Cells[0].Value = ima;
                                            currentRow.Cells[1].Value = p.ProcessName;
                                            currentRow.Cells[2].Value = memoryUsage;
                                            currentRow.Cells[3].Value = status;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                                                ima, p.ProcessName,memoryUsage, status);
                                        }
                                        rcurIndex++;
                            }
                        }
                        catch ( Exception e)
                        {
                            string t = "error";
                        }
                }
                if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
                {
                    for (int i = rcurIndex; i < rcount - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rcurIndex);
                    }
                }
        }
```

This is the DoubleBufferedd method:

```
public static void DoubleBufferedd(DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
        {
            Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
        }
```

And this is the method i get the memory usage:

```
public static string getallmemoryusage(string processName)
        {
            var counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", processName);
            privateMemeory = (counter.NextValue() / 1024 / 1024).ToString();//string.Format("Private memory: {0}k", counter.NextValue() / 1024 / 1024);
            return privateMemeory;
        }
```

The question is why it stop in the backgorundworker dowork event after some times it does work ?

Comment: Does it work properly if you run the executable instead of debugging it in the IDE?  I have seen timers do funny things in the debugger.

Comment: For now it keep working when running from the hard disk. I will let it keep running to see how it work.